# how to get group by cumulative concat for string values in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012, logic

```
declare  @t table
(
    year int, 
    month int,
    SomeName varchar(100)
)

insert into @t
select 2015, 1, 'Ashok'
union
select 2015, 2, 'Ram'
union
select 2015, 3, 'Ashok'
union
select 2016, 1, 'Raj'
union
select 2016, 2, 'Raj'

select * from @t
```

the above  select returns me the following.

```
year    month  SomeName
2015    1      Ashok
2015    2      Ram
2015    3      Ashok
2016    1      Raj
2016    2      Raj
```

How do i get the following..

```
year    month   name    CumSrome
2015    1       Ashok   Ashok
2015    2       Ram     Ashok,Ram
2015    3       Ashok   Ashok,Ram
2016    1       Raj     Raj
2016    2       Raj     Raj
```

TIA

Comment: You are talking about *cumulative*... Is this grouped by year? Why is `Raj` alone?

Comment: Explain how you got to your desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
declare  @t table
(
    year int, month int,
    SomeName varchar(100)
);

insert into @t
select 2015, 1, 'Ashok'
union all
select 2015, 2, 'Ram'
union all
select 2015, 3, 'Ashok'
union all
select 2016, 1, 'Raj'
union all
select 2016, 2, 'Raj';

SELECT t.*
      ,CumumlativeConcatPerYear.Names
FROM @t AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + SomeName
        FROM @t AS x
        WHERE x.year=t.year AND x.month<=t.month 
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,2,'')
) AS CumumlativeConcatPerYear(Names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the STUFF command combined with FOR XML PATH command to concatenate the string together.

https://sqlwhisper.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/stuff-and-for-xml-path-for-string-concatenation/

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Yes it is usefull but it only helps the OP to find and answer and is no answer by itself

Comment: Sorry, I've only been posting for 9 days, still have a lot to learn about how this site works.